# Match hyphen character from a string to make an array output

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, preg-match-all

I have a string that should contain a name and a date of registration:

```
Dipak Misra - 18 Nov 2018 10:20
```

I want to convert this string into array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Dipak Misra [1] => 18 Nov 2018 [2] => 10:20 )
```

I am using `preg_match_all()` function:

```
$re = '/\w+(?:[-\s]\w+)*/'; 
$str = "Dipak Misra - 18 Nov 2018 10:20"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

I am getting output Like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Dipak Misra [1] => 18 Nov 2018 10 [2] => 20 )
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

If the format of that string does not change, you could split on either a space, hyphen space, or split on a space where on the left and the right side a digit is present instead of matching.

`- |(?<=\d) (?=\d)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/47P403/1)

For example:

```
print_r(preg_split("/ - |(?<=\d) (?=\d)/", "Dipak Misra - 18 Nov 2018 10:20"));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dipak Misra
    [1] => 18 Nov 2018
    [2] => 10:20
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match()` with `([^-]+)\s+-\s+(.*)\s(\d+:\d+)` as pattern instead

```
$re = '/([^-]+)\s+-\s+(.*)\s(\d+:\d+)/'; 
$str = "Dipak Misra - 18 Nov 2018 10:20"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
unset($matches[0]);
print_r($matches);
```

[Check result in demo](https://3v4l.org/lQpOr)

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/(\w+\s\w+)\s-\s([0-9]{2}\s\w+\s[0-9]{4})\s([0-9]+:[0-9]+)/";
$chain = "Dipak Misra - 18 Nov 2018 10:20";
preg_match_all($pattern, $chain, $matches);

$data = [
    'chain' => $chain,
    'pattern' => $pattern,
    'name' => $matches[1],
    'date' => $matches[2],
    'time' => $matches[3]
];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "<pre>";
```

---

the output

[image]